# How to make a color changing window?

Tags: java, swing

Ok so I'm having trouble with my homework assignment. I'm trying to create a window showing the color selected then have a combo box below it with various colors in it. But I don't know where to start.
I can't post an image of it on here cause my rep points are too low. So I'll draw a little picture on here.

```
-----------------
 --------------
||             ||
||             ||
||             ||
 --------------
-----------------
      [GREEN]^
```

Can anyone help me?

Ok tried working on this from what I've read and came up with this, but its not turning out to what I want. I got the combo box but the colors aren't showing like I would like. Can anyone help with this?

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

    class Colors extends JFrame implements ItemListener

    {
    Choice chooseColor = new Choice();
    Label lblQts = new Label("Choose color you like : ");

    public Colors(String title)
    {
    super(title);
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    chooseColor.addItem("red");
    chooseColor.addItem("green");
    chooseColor.addItem("blue");

    add(lblQts);
    add(chooseColor);

    chooseColor.addItemListener(this);
    }   

    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e)
    {   
    String c;
    Color color;
    c = chooseColor.getSelectedItem();
    color=Color.getColor(c);


    setBackground(color);
    }


    }

public static void main(String[] args)
    {


        Colors objColor = new Colors("Color Chooser");
        objColor.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        objColor.setSize(400,400);
        objColor.setVisible(true);


    }
```

Comment: We're not a code writing service, try it and come to us when you have programming issues!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by reading the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Combo Boxes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html). You can add Color objects to the combo box and then create a custom renderer to display the color.

Then you can add an ActionListener to the combo box. The tutorial also has a section on `"How to Write an Action Listener"`. When the listener fires you can then change the background of your component with the selected color.